# Get Unique Values from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique

```
var arr = ["THYROID","CARDIAC","CARDIAC,DIABETES","METABOLIC,ARTHRITIS","RENAL DISEASES,DIABETES","LIVER DISEASES,HEPATITIS","LIVER DISEASES,CANCER,METABOLIC","LIVER DISEASES,HEPATITIS,ARTHRITIS,METABOLIC"]
```

Above is my Code, 
I need to fetch unique Values from this array using Javascript.

Like, what i expect is:
If i ask for Unique Values , it should get me :

```
var arr = ["THYROID","CARDIAC","DIABETES","METABOLIC","RENAL DISEASES","LIVER DISEASES,"CANCER",ARTHRITIS","HEPATITIS"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of strings, you can just create an object using those strings as keys, then get the keys from that object.

**Create the object**

```
for (var t = {}, i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
  t[arr[i]] = 0;
```

**Create an array from the objects keys**

```
// Modern browsers only
arr = Object.keys(t);

// In older browsers you can use the polyfill from the link below,
// or just loop through the object like this:
arr = [];
for (var k in t)
  arr.push(k);
```

[Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)